Why is `__name__` of `__init__` different when importing directly?
I have a directory structure like this:
.
├── main.py
└── silly_test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── foo.py

# main.py
import silly_test.foo
import silly_test.__init__ # This line is unusual - I wouldn't typically do this.  

# silly_test/__init__.py
print(f"Init name: {__name__}")

# silly_test/foo.py
print("Hi from foo")

This prints:
Init name: silly_test
Hi from foo
Init name: silly_test.__init__    <-- WHAT?!

I am surprised by the last line of the output for multiple reasons.

Generally top level code in a file is only executed once.  To my surprise, this is executing twice.
The __name__ property of the file is different.

What is going on here?  :)
Are there other cases where you can have a many-to-one relationship between __name__ and a file?

I guess that in the second import __init__ is just treated like any other module in package silly_test.

__init__.py in a folder silly_test is automatically called when you import silly_test.whatever (or, for that matter, just import silly_test). At this point, __name__ is silly_test, because it is the name of the package. That is where your first Init name: silly_test comes from.
When you import silly_test.__init__ explicitly, __name__ becomes silly_test.__init__ (because that is exactly the file that you asked for).

But there is no import silly_test; just import silly_test.foo, so why is the package also imported if only the module is imported?

in order to import modules inside packages (the .foo), Python will always import the package  - and that implies running any code in the  __init__.py file directly inside it.

completing this:  what makes Python decide not to re-import a module is the key in the sys.modules dict containing the module name. import silly_test.foo will create the entries "silly_test"  and "slilly_test.foo" in that dictionary. When silly_test.__init__ is explicitly asked for, the key silly_test.__init__ is filled in.
It is likely that just explictly importing silly_test.__init__ , without the import slilly_test.foo statement will also trigger the module being executed twice.

@jsbueno "in order to import modules inside packages (the .foo), Python will always import the package": out of curiosity, can you point to where that is documented?

@9769953 - Sure. One such place is here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html - in the first few paragraphs one can read "[...]The search operation of the import statement is defined as a call to the __import__() function, with the appropriate arguments [...] [A]  call to __import__() performs [...] the module creation operation. While certain side-effects may occur, such as the importing of parent packages, [...] "

@jsbueno Thanks! Although not precisely what I hoped for. E.g., it states "may occur, such as the importing of parent packages". Section 5.2.1 (bottom) also mentions the import steps explicitly, but still not as mandated by the language. So I'm curious if this is specified for the language, or technically an implementation detail.

as a library author, I´d be very surprised if that would not happen, and likely some bugs would arise - even if it is an implementation detail - which I don´t think so - other implementations woud likely copy this behavior or risk having software not working.
Either way, at the end of that document there are the import system-related PEPs.

@9769953 And what about if you read all the document linked and get to the part that states: "Importing parent.one will implicitly execute parent/init.py and parent/one/init.py. Subsequent imports of parent.two or parent.three will execute parent/two/init.py and parent/three/init.py respectively." ?

@jsbueno You're quoting section 5.2.1 that I already referred to. But to me, that doesn't set the language rules; it just tells us what happens. So that could, i.m.o., still be a CPython implementation detail. I'm curious if there is any documentation, say a PEP of sorts, that specifies something like "importing a module or subpackage within a package shall also import the parent package".

No, this document is the official reference for the "Import System" - it is not a guide on cPython implementation details: it is the law. The former quote contains the wording "may occur", just to give the margin for other side effects. This section states it in as much a hard way as possible, and is more official than any PEP could be.
